# How I can delete a file in a folder which is smaller in size using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-os

I have folder consist of some files, I  need to delete the file which is smaller in size. I am able to get the size of the by code given below, But I am confused that how to delete the file which is smaller in size

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Path):
    for fn in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fn)
        size = os.stat(path).st_size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to identify the smallest file in size in each folder, then try the following code before you actually delete anything. Since your code already gets the file sizes, I modified it slightly to capture the file names and sizes in a dictionary for each folder. That makes it easy to return the file name with the smallest size using the min() function.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(stpath):
    d = {} # intialize dict
    for fn in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fn)
        size = os.stat(path).st_size
        # capture file name and size for files in root
        d[fn] = size
    # some folders may be empty
    if d:
        # get the file name of the file with the smallest size
        smallestfile = min(d, key=d.get)
        print(root, smallestfile, d[smallestfile])
```

Of course, I only printed the smallest file in each folder. When you confirm that this is what you want, you can delete them instead.